# latex package gb4e: How to make the first line "running text"

Tags: descriptive-linguistics, latex

I am writing a grammatical description of a language using the package gb4e to produce the interlinear glosses. The editor has asked that the first line of the gloss appear as running text, i.e. is not aligned word-by-word with the second and third lines, but just appears with one space between words.

Simply put, I want the text in the \gll line to NOT align word-by-word with the text in the following line. However, I still want to the following two lines to align word-by-word. Is this even possible?

I've been fiddling with this, but can't figure out how to do it. Any advice would be great!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep{: }}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\stepcounter{section} % So that the labels have different values
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{lineno}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\linenumbers

\section{-\textit{rqsa} `Affirmative suffix (\textsc{aff}'}


\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \glll Ikall ibaw an\textipa{\texttslig} t'amruwata\textipa{\textctt}i jaqqnuchtakilla. \\
    \{ika-ll iba-w an\textipa{\texttslig}.  t'am(u)ru-w-ata-\textipa{\textctt}i jaqq(a)-nuch(u)-taki-lla \}\\
    that-\textsc{top} no-\textsc{decl} very good-\textsc{cop.vbz-re-neg/irr} intoxicate-\textsc{purp-ben-top} \\
    \trans `That really wasn't very good (preparation) for intoxication.'
    \label{ex:good}
\end{exe}


\end{document}
'''
```

Comment: Have you considered asking on the latex site? Maybe this question can be migrated there.